# Layout restarts after device's rotation

Tags: java, android, layout, rotation

I did a simple application with 2 buttons (start and exit) and an empty TextView. If i push the start button, a TextView will be update. My problem is that if i rotate the device, my layout will restart (if start was pushed, the TextView will become empty again. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It because activity recreate after screen rotate. Simple fix is adding `android:id` to your `TextView` at xml.

Answer (score 1):

Android automatically destroys the activity and recreates it adapting it to the new orientation of the screen when the device is rotated.

Comment: Avoidance of the activity destruction and recreation is inevitable but what you can do is force the activity to maintain a fixed orientation. or save what you need to in the saveInstanceState(Bundle) method of the activity and later retireve it from the same bundle passed on to it via the onCreate(Bundle); or restoreInstanceState(); also ingoring onConfigChange() is an option but is highly discouraged.

Comment: I noticed only one post didn't get downvoted and that was fishers. Fishy.

Comment: @Samuel  Could be because his is the only correct answer whilst the ones which have been downvoted are simply wrong?

Answer (score -3):

If you dont want activity to recreate on orientation change you can add this line

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

in Android manifet for that Activity..
for eg:-

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

[Reference here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)